# Wiremock fake that a service is down

Tags: wiremock

In my current setup, if one of my services is down and a request is made to that service, I send a certain HTTP code in the response.

Now to test this I'm using Wiremock to mock my service. Is there a way to mock that the service is unavailable and return a specific response as a result?

I've tried looking through the Wiremock code but there are barely any comments for the methods. I've also tried looking through the docs and I couldn't find anything about bringing down the service.

Comment: why not use normal mock only? I am sorry If i did not understand your questions, but lets say on your service being down you return 500, Now why not just mock the service and return 500?

Answer (score 2):

you could try `ResponseDefinitionBuilder.aResponse().withFault(Fault.CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER)`, `ResponseDefinitionBuilder.serviceUnavailable()` or simply point your client to a port that is guaranteed to have no listeners, depending on what exactly would you like to test with

> service is unavailable and return a specific response as a result